# Specify Git Tool to use in Multi-OS Agent Jenkins Environment for Declarative Pipeline

Tags: linux, windows, git, jenkins

I'm fairly new to Jenkins but I'm trying to set up a Multi OS Agent environment. Jenkins Master is on Windows Server 2019, and I have a separate Windows Server 2019 agent (Laconia) and an Ubuntu 20.04 agent (Java8Europa) both successfully connected via SSH. I've also configured Git on both instances and I have created two Git tool locations in the global tools config as shown below and confirmed that these work on the individual machines.

[image: Git Tools Location]

The problem I have is that even if I set the individual nodes to use the correct Git tool as shown below, if I try to execute a simple declarative pipeline job, it will only ever use the Git instance which is at the top of the list above (WindowsGit). My declarative pipeline starts with a Windows Script which executes correctly but then when it tries to execute the Linux shell script on the Linux box, it fails as it attempts to use WindowsGit.

[image: Java8Europa Tool Locations]

I'll include the console log output below, but is there anyway how I can force via the Jenkinsfile which git tool should be used per agent? I did read that there are some tool locations which are ignored by the agents and there are some articles which suggest Git is one of these and the fact that if I switch the order of the Git installations to have the LinuxGit at the top, the pipeline fails to run the Windows script which would seem to support those articles. Any other way I can get around this?

```
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] bat
administrator@LACONIA C:\Jenkins\WorkingRepo\workspace\ReidacusOrg_siplogscanner_main@2>hello.bat
administrator@LACONIA C:\Jenkins\WorkingRepo\workspace\ReidacusOrg_siplogscanner_main@2>echo "This   is coming from a Windows Script" 
"This is coming from a Windows Script"
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Say Hello)
[Pipeline] node
Running on Java8(Europa) in /home/andrew/jenkins/workspace/ReidacusOrg_siplogscanner_main
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential GitHubAPIAccess
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /home/andrew/jenkins/workspace/ReidacusOrg_siplogscanner_main
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:997)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:752)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:161)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:154)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:376)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to Java8(Europa)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1800)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1001)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor882.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1221)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1299)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing git command: "C:\Git\bin\git.exe" init /home/andrew/jenkins/workspace/ReidacusOrg_siplogscanner_main
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2457)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2380)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2376)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1923)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:995)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""C:\Git\bin\git.exe"" (in directory "/home/andrew/jenkins/workspace/ReidacusOrg_siplogscanner_main"): error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:252)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:221)
at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:996)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:508)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2443)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 20 more
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Say Bye)
Stage "Say Bye" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Cloning repository https://github.com/reidacus/siplogscanner.git 
"C:\Git\bin\git.exe" init /home/andrew/jenkins/workspace/ReidacusOrg_siplogscanner_main # 
timeout=10
GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'**
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the approach of specifying 2 git configurations. Otherwise, you have to change every job. Just have one configuration and override the **tool location** at the agent/ node level. Only specify different tools where the variant matters. In your [pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/07/declarative-maven-project/#adding-tools-to-pipeline) you'd [reference](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#tools) :

```
tools {
    jdk 'jdk1.8' 
}
```

**Global configuration**
[image: Global Tool config]

**Node Configuration**
[image: Agent configuration]

The Tools selector is intended to choose flavors of tools (jdk ver, openjdk vs oraclejdk, etc.). You override the tool location at the node level. My complete example was JDK, since versions matter, but also win/linux location differ. Git is just git.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I remove the LinuxGit instance from the global tool config how would I override the location of that tool in the Jenkinsfile? I thought that the configuration had to exist with a tool location in the global tools config before I could call this with the tools directive? I also tried to leave the LinuxGit config in place and tried the following but its the same result as before. 
      tools {
        git 'LinuxGit'
      }

Comment: OK, I managed to get this to work. Rather than specifying the git locations in the global tool config, I shortened this just to 'git', scaled back to one, but then just overrode this on the Windows node to use a specific tool location. Both the Linux and Windows instance now work. Thanks!

Comment: Right. The Tools selector is intended to choose flavors of tools (jdk ver, openjdk vs oraclejdk, etc.). You override the tool location at the node level. My complete example was JDK, since versions matter, but also win/linux location differ. Git is just git. Worth an upvote too?