# How to write a pipeline script for building the project in AWS?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am very new to the AWS part , i want to build and deploy my project for that i am selecting pipeline script in jenkins i am writing some script for building , i am getting errors on my console like this

```
Started by user saitarun
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample_pipelinejob
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (clone repository and clean project)
[Pipeline] sh
+ git clone https://github.com/saitarun135/ADDRESS_BOOK
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sample_pipelinejob@tmp/durable-8b9fc0cc/script.sh: line 1: git: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

How to rectify this error and How to build my project , please help me to fix this thing..
Following images are my configurations of my pipeline .
[image: My cloning repository]
[image: My pipeline script]

Comment: Please configure git on global tool configuration section.

Comment: Hello @Dashrath Mundkar, i need to give path of my local gitbash  na ..?

Comment: yes you have to add from host machine where jenkins is running

Answer (score 2):

> How to install git

If you `git` installation path is not the same between your main Jenkins instance, and the Jenkins agent, you would need to [specify that path at the agent level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66619770/6309), in the Node configuration.

[image: https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/article_attachments/360065141291/db28cbd4_tool_locations.png]

(Image from "[cloudbees Using PATH in Git Configuration / In the node configurations](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048202171-Using-PATH-in-Git-Configuration#inthenodeconfigurations)")

You might need to install Git on that instance: `sudo yum install git`

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
git: command not found
```

shows that either `git` is not installed on your `Jenkins` machine or `git` is not in your `PATH` variable.

Comment: How to rectify or How to install git in jenkins

Comment: It depends on your operating system. I assume it's a linux system? Which system is it?

Comment: My local machine is windows 10 and the cloud instance is AMI(amazon linux)

Comment: For the Windows machine you can download and install git here: https://git-scm.com/download/win For the amazon machine I assume you have to use the command `sudo apt install git`